# roll a dice and print each occurrence

Tags: arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I want to Prompt a user for a series of integers that represent rolls of a six-sided die: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6. When they are done entering in the values, the user should enter -1. would I Use a while loop and the Scanner method nextInt()?
I need an array of integers to keep track of the number of occurrences of each die value as they are read in. For example, dieCount[3] can represent the number of 3's that have been rolled.
then print the number of occurrences for each die value. here's what I have so far, but it gives me an endless loop...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DieRoll {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int SENTINEL = -1;

        System.out.print("Enter die values, -1 to quit > ");
        int dieValue = scan.nextInt();

        int [] dieArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

        while (dieValue == intArray(i)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dieArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(dieArray[i] + ": " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you inputting -1? In this code you are taking input just for once and not in while loop

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty certain that code won't even compile since you have not declared anything called `intArray`.

However, assuming that's a typo on your part, an infinite loop is almost certainly caused by the fact that you get only the *first* value from the user then loop until it's `-1` (presumably - it's hard to tell since the code is defective but it's the most likely explanation based on what we have), printing out the accumulated counts *each* time. That will loop for eternity.

What you need to do is to have a loop asking for values until you get `-1`, accumulating them into your counts. Then *after* that loop, print out the counts.

The *pseudo-code* would go something like this:

```
create array count[0..5], all zero

userInput = nextint()
while userInput != -1:
    if userInput < 1 or userInput > 6:
        output "Invalid value ${userInput}, please use -1 or 1..6"
    else:
        increment count[userInput - 1]
    userInput = nextint()

for valThrown in 0..5:
    output "You threw ${valThrown} ${count[valThrown - 1]} times"
```

*Your* mission, should you choose to accept it, is to understand how that pseudo-code works and then translate that into your *actual* language. You seem perfectly aware of the actual constructs to use since you've used them all, albeit in an ... err ... interesting way, in your supplied code :-)